# convert date format from 9/15/12 to 255 in perl

Tags: perl

I was wondering if someone could show me how to convert 9/15/12 to 255 format.
Something in php from getdate array you can get ydate.

Comment: 255 format? huh?

Comment: September 15th is the 255th day of 2012.

Comment: @mob, Actually, it's the 259th, so maybe that's not what he wants either.

Comment: Then I meant that September 12th is the 255th day of 2015. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking how you can get the `1 <= yday <= 366` day representation of a date, similar to `yday` in php's `getdate()`. As is common in PERL, there's more than one way to do it. The simplest mechanism would be to use `localtime()` for today's date:

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);
```

If you want to do it for a different date, I'd probably use the [`TimeDate` CPAN module](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-1.20/)

```
use Date::Parse;

print time2str("%j",str2time("9/15/2012"));
```

Comment: Good point, updating answer based on that. Missed that it wasn't the 15th today -.-

Answer (score 2):

I think Tawnos's mentioning php's `yday` from `getdate()` is on target.  Here's one option (assuming 2012 is the year in your date string):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Calc qw/Day_of_Year/;

my $date = '9/15/12';
my ( $month, $day, $year ) = split '/', $date;
my $doy = Day_of_Year( "20$year", $month, $day ) - 1;

print $doy; # (0 - 365)
```

Output:

```
258
```

Comment: That's the answer, although I think you should mention why you substracting '1' - cause often you need to get days starts from one (e.g. http://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/julian_calendar.shtml), so there would be no need to substract

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the day of the year? That would be day 258 (0-based) or the 259th day (1-based), though. Using only core Perl:

```
use Time::Local qw( timegm );
my $date = '9/15/12';
my ($m,$d,$y) = split(qr{/}, $date);
my $epoch = timegm(0,0,0, $d,$m-1,$y);
my $yday = ( gmtime($epoch) )[7];   # 258 (0-based index)
```

Note that `timegm`+`gmtime` is applicable no matter the time zone of the date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only function [`strftime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX#strftime) from core module [`POSIX`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX).

```
use strict;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

print strftime "%j", localtime(time);
```

Comment: Only half and answer; the input format is `9/15/12`, not epoch time.

Comment: Don't need to use `strftime`, when julian date *offset* is the 8th item returned from `localtime` to *use* `strftime`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, using the core module [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime(shift,"%m/%d/%y");
print $t->yday, "\n";
```

The day output is zero-relative: January 01 = 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $dt = '9/15/2012';
my ( $m, $d, $y ) = split( '/', $dt );
my $t = POSIX::mktime( 0, 0, 0, $d, $m - 1, $y - 1900 );
say [ localtime $t ]->[7] - 3;
```

Julian date (minus 1) is slot 7 in the list return from `localtime` and `gmtime`. 
Why subtract 3? I don't know; Sept 15 is 259 Julian. Still it performs the function mapping '9/15/2012' to 255.